# VLC in Xubuntu 15.04

Tags: xubuntu, vlc, 15.04

I am trying to install VLC on Xubuntu 15.04 (clean installation), however I am getting this error:

```
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libfreerdp1 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

when I try to install vlc-nox as well it adds even more depencies

```
 vlc-nox : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                    libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.18) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libdvbpsi8 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.5.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libgnutls28 (>= 3.2.10-0) but it is not installable
```

How can I get it work?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Third Party Repository for VLC?

Comment: No, but when I'm checking more into depth I see that I've installed ffmpeg from ppa:mc3man/trusty-media which also has vlc in his repo, so I guess that is a problem, however I wonder is there a way to solve it without disabling this ppa temporarily?

Comment: And what happens when you remove the PPA and it's packages and install VLC?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found out that it's not necessary to add another ppa since mc3man's repo is for trusty, I can just use this:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc -t vivid
```

@xangua this of course works but I was looking for a better solution

@whatanohelpforum @Fat-Mind those solutions don't work because mc3man repositary is higher in priority and it's trying to install from that repo

Answer (score -1):

Please try to remove and install it again

to remove the vlc

```
Sudo apt-get remove vlc
```

to install it again

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

to install extra packages for VLC

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

check and advise with the output

Answer (score -1):

unstable 3.0 worked for me

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install vlc
> ```